# Is it possible to change Azure Elastic Pool server version

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-elasticpool

I created a new instance of SQL elastic pool server, the displayed version of sql server is 12.0.2000.8. Is it possible to upgrade it to 13.x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL Databases always run on latest stable version of the SQL Server database engine.(Refer to [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-database-paas-overview?view=azuresql) for more details).

You can run below queries to check the same after creating the database:

select @@version as version;
select serverproperty('ProductVersion') as [version],serverproperty('Edition') as [edition];
SELECT name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases;

You can find the version using the SQL query but that will always show you v12.x.x.x.

Hope this will help.

Thanks